# Any example of routers who are NOT a switch too

Tags: routing, switch, router

I'm looking for any router that is indeed only a router (a device that routes traffic from one network to another) and not those "routers" that we see nowadays in people's home that are router + switch in one package.

Does it exist? I don't intend to buy it, so it can be old and not available for purchase anymore. I just need to know for searching purposes.

Comment: Questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, but many business-grade routers can be had without a switch module.

Comment: If you take a look at my question you would see that I'm explicitly NOT asking for consumer-grade hardware, as you can see by `and not those "routers" that we see nowadays in people's home that are router + switch in one package`...

Comment: Right, and my comment tells you about business-grade routers. I also did not vote to close the question. Many times, with business-grade routers, you must purchase a switch module for the router if you want it to switch, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any router by default runs data path for layer 1,2 and 3 while it runs control plane for all the 5 layers. You cannot skip a layer in the data path at a router.

However, seeing your question you want a router that does no do switching. This is definately possible. How the forwarding takes place, depends on the lookup table it refers to.
If it refers to the L3 forward table, it will be routing and if it refers to the L2 forwarding table it will do switching